# Powershell HTTP Post to Service Bus Queue returns 401

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-servicebus-queues, sas-token

Trying to submit a message to a service bus queue I have set up, and keep getting a 401 Unauthorized return.

I've tried configuring the SAS token myself using this method

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
$NameSpaceName = "serviceBusNameSpace"
$QueueName = "myQueueName"
$PolicyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
$body = "test message"

$Namespace = (Get-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $namespacename).Name
$key = (Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $namespacename -Name $PolicyName).PrimaryKey

$origin = [DateTime]"1/1/1970 00:00" 
$Expiry = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)    

#compute the token expiration time.
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $origin -End $Expiry 
$tokenExpirationTime = [Convert]::ToInt32($diff.TotalSeconds)

#Create a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class and set the key to UTF8 for the size of $Key
$hmacsha = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.Key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Key)

$scope = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/"
#create the string that will be used when cumputing the hash
$stringToSign = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($scope) + "`n" + $tokenExpirationTime

#Compute hash from the HMACSHA256 instance we created above using the size of the UTF8 string above.
$hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
#Convert the hash to base 64 string
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
$fullResourceURI = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName"
#create the token
$token = [string]::Format([Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, `
         "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", `
         [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($fullResourceURI), `
         [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($signature), `
         $tokenExpirationTime, $PolicyName) 

$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$token"; "Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8" }
$uri = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName/messages"
$headers.Add("BrokerProperties", "{}")

#Invoke-WebRequest call.
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

I've also tried generating it through a built in cmdlet in Az.ServiceBus

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
$NameSpaceName = "serviceBusNameSpace"
$QueueName = "myQueueName"
$PolicyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"

$body = "test message"
$expiry = (Get-Date).AddHours(2)
$authRule = Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $NamespaceName
$token = New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken -AuthorizationRuleId $authRule.Id -KeyType Primary -ExpiryTime $Expiry

$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "SharedAccessSignature $($token.SharedAccessSignature)"; "Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8" }
$uri = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName/messages"
$headers.Add("BrokerProperties", "{}")

#Invoke-WebRequest call.
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

Both give me a 401 unauthorized error

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:9 char:17
+ ... $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Pos ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Is there a setting I need to configure for my queue within the azure portal?

**Have found solution. UTC time was originally expiring token before even sending, in addition to malformed SAS signature**

Final code edit below

```
$key = (Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $namespacename -Name $PolicyName).PrimaryKey

$origin = [DateTime]"1/1/1970 00:00" 
$Expiry = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(20)
$Expiry = $Expiry.ToUniversalTime()    

#compute the token expiration time.
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $origin -End $Expiry 
$tokenExpirationTime = [Convert]::ToInt32($diff.TotalSeconds)


$uri = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName/messages"
$scope = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName"
#create the string that will be used when cumputing the hash
$stringToSign = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($scope) + "`n" + $tokenExpirationTime

#Create a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class and set the key to UTF8 for the size of $Key
$hmacsha = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.Key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Key)


#Compute hash from the HMACSHA256 instance we created above using the size of the UTF8 string above.
$hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
#Convert the hash to base 64 string
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)

#create the token
$token = [string]::Format([Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, `
        "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", `
        [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($scope), `
        [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($signature), `
        $tokenExpirationTime, $PolicyName) 

$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$token"}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8")

#Invoke-WebRequest call.
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: In the first case, can you try by setting your `scope` to `https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName` instead of `https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/`?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I have tried that route as well and it has produced the same "401" unauthorized error as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See post edit.

Token expiration time wasn't converted to UTC, making it always expired, in addition to not having the SaS token configuration string formed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have made some changes in your script and it is working fine.

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
$Namespace = "serviceBusNameSpace"
$QueueName = "myQueueName"
$PolicyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
$body = "test message"

$key = (Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $Namespace -Name $PolicyName).PrimaryKey

$origin = [DateTime]"1/1/1970 00:00" 
$Expiry = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)    

#compute the token expiration time.
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $origin -End $Expiry 
$tokenExpirationTime = [Convert]::ToInt32($diff.TotalSeconds)

#Create a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class and set the key to UTF8 for the size of $Key
$hmacsha = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.Key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Key)

#create the string that will be used when cumputing the hash
$stringToSign = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Namespace) + "`n" + $tokenExpirationTime

#Compute hash from the HMACSHA256 instance we created above using the size of the UTF8 string above.
$hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
#Convert the hash to base 64 string
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)

#create the token
$token = [string]::Format([Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, `
        "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", `
        [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Namespace), `
        [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($signature), `
        $tokenExpirationTime, $PolicyName) 

$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$token"; "Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8" }
$uri = "https://$Namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName/messages"
$headers.Add("BrokerProperties", "{}")

#Invoke-WebRequest call.
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

The changes which I have made are:

1. You don't need to create scope variable. You need to pass the **$Namespace** to stringToSign.
2. You don't need to use **Get-AzServiceBusNamespace** to get namespace name as you are already taking this as user input.

Comment: I have tested your code against the Queue I have in my service bus namespace and I am still receiving a 401 unauthorized response. This key is the Shared Access Policy key from the service bus namespace, do I need the key from the Shared Access Policy on my queue in the namespace maybe??

Comment: Also, according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas) the full resource URI needs to be in the Shared Access Signature token, not just the namespace

Comment: But we send the $scope as full resource URI in stringToSign, we get the same error as you mentioned. Also when I changed it to Namespace name it worked for me.

Comment: I have updated the code. Check it now there was typing error of "Namespace" variable while fetching key.

Comment: I have retested the code and am still receiving a "401 Unauthorized" response

Comment: Was able to find problem, have edited original post to reflect solution found.